# Rendering elements around a central point

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a bit of a tricky question I couldn't find the answer to. Basically, This is what I have:
[image]

In the center is a search box (fixed to the center of the page), and around it are dynamically loaded search results of differing sizes (although, if need be these can be restricted). Thing is, they need to "wrap" around the search box after the results have been loaded. My normal go-to is floating, but this isn't really going to work, as the box isn't aligned to a particular direction.

I've looked at jQuery Masonry for a solution, but it isn't going to work for me (doesn't detect fixed elements, doesn't work from a point).

Any pointers in terms of solutions or Google-Fu would be much appreciated.

Comment: start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: Thanks a bundle. One of the hardest things about this problem was trying to describe it in words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to packing textures of different sizes on a square. Have a look at this algorithm: http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/default.html

Since you have a central fixed box, maybe you can divide your available space in 4 rectangles and then pack the boxes into them.

Comment: You know, I was thinking of using the quadrant approach (populating them in turn) but I wasn't sure if I was on the right track. Thanks for the tip!